# Three.js spotlight barn doors

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm using three.js to create a scene with spotlights.

How could I create a barn door effect for the lights? Is this possible using three.js?

I've tried to block the light with very small cubes acting as barn doors but it doesn't work well.

Here is an example of the sort of control I'd like to be able to have: 
[Barn Doors](http://lowel.com/edu/light_controls/barndoors.html)

[image: Light with barn doors. These shutters move close in or spread out to direct light]

Comment: Could you share a screenshot or image that illustrates what a "barn door" effect is?

Comment: @mrdoob I think this use case would be also covered if Three.js supported light cookies / textures on lights, as described here: http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Components/class-Light.html   Barn door effect could then be done with dynamically created canvas texture. Just saying, it would be very nice feature ;) I have tried to implement it myself, but it's a bit above my skills, here's something about my and Popov's adventures with it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15665074/calculating-the-position-on-spotlight-cone-in-phong-shader

Answer (score 1):

My advice is to make due with the built-in parameters of a Three.js spotlight. You can see a demo [here](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/lights/SpotLight) which is quite detailed. You can adjust the:

- Intensity
- Distance
- Angle (similar to moving all barn doors together)
- Penumbra
- Decay

The only way to recreate it is as you have already described; although I'd use planes instead of cubes.

If you edit your original question to include some code and describe what "didn't work so well," I can offer potential solutions to that.