# Using soure material in casted shadow

Tags: opengl, three.js, webgl

What is the correct way to apply a material in a shadow, to achieve effects such as stained glass ?

[image: example]
<sub>(source: [123rf.com](http://us.123rf.com/400wm/400/400/chernetskiy/chernetskiy1002/chernetskiy100200015/6510854-stained-glass-windows-with-light-coming-from-behind.jpg))</sub>

I'm currently able to project a shadow, but it is only grey and does not compose with the source object material.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15665074/calculating-the-position-on-spotlight-cone-in-phong-shader

Comment: Are you referring to the light shafts? This is an application of volumetric lighting, it is usually simulated using scattering these days. There are actual shadow techniques that use the properties of material transmission through air/smoke but they are very expensive and "god rays" (single-scattering effect) as a separate pass unrelated to shadowing  are considered good enough in real-time graphics these days.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood everything correctly, you are asking how to create shadows that support transparent objects?

If so, then you could try this:

When creating shadow map, you could write the depth into the alpha value, and if the objects is opaque write 0,0,0 (shadow color) into RGB, and if it's transparent, write it's color into the RGB.

So you end up with shadow map that holds both depth values (A) that you'll use to check whether the object's in the light or in the shadow, and if it's in the shadow you apply the shadow with the color that's written into the RGB part of the shadow map.

For this purpose you would have to use 32bit framebuffer when rendering shadow map.

Hope this helps.