# Project image and update texture on a Three.js object

Tags: three.js, textures, project

I am building a paint tool with which want to "paint" an image on an object texture.
I have found a very interesting example of texture projection here:

http://www.evpopov.com/threejstest/test_spot_projtexture.html

I was just wondering there is a way to "paint" this projection on the object texture?

This is related to this post:

[Calculating the position on spotlight cone in Phong shader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15665074/calculating-the-position-on-spotlight-cone-in-phong-shader)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The subject is answered in this thread:

[THREEJS : Vertex Color Baking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27697456/threejs-saving-texture-from-fragment-shader)

There are no easy way to do it.