# THREEJS : Vertex Color Baking

Tags: opengl-es, three.js, webgl

When coloring a mesh using vertex coloration, how does one save the colors as a texture?

For example, if a mesh is colored based on its normals (similar to [this example](http://threejs.org/examples/#canvas_materials_normal)), how can one create a .png for the texture?

For this purpose, it can be assumed that this mesh has texture coordinates.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? I'm not sure what you mean by "PNG for the texture", and which "event" you are talking about. Do you want to save an image of the rendering you produced?

Comment: I don't want to save an image of the rendering.  I want to save an image of the unwrapped fragment shader.

Comment: Posted previous comment too quickly.  Suppose I have a mobius strip with a texture mapped to it.  Each vertex has a texture coordinate, so I can unwrap the texture (or unwrap the mesh) in accordance with these texture coordinates.  I want to do the same with a fragment shader, but save out the image created by it.  In other words, I want to turn a mesh with a fragment shader into a mesh with a texture referencing an image.  The two meshes will look the same, but the underlying material is different.