# Three.js fragment shader: save the texture modifications

Tags: three.js, textures, fragment-shader

My issue: load a mesh with an image texture (png, jpg, etc.), modify the texture with fragment shader, get it back and save it as new image (png, jpg). Is it possible?

Comment: As far as I know, a fragment shader modifies all the pixels you are displaying and does not operate on a "texture" by itself. Thus, you cannot really save those modifications, except when you maybe render a full screen size quad with the texture into a render target and save the render target but overall, you should look for glTexImage2D  and glTexSubImage2D if you want to modify textures by themselves. But this is pure GLES/WebGL and has nothing to do with Three.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The subject is answered in this thread:

[THREEJS : Vertex Color Baking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27697456/threejs-saving-texture-from-fragment-shader)

There are no easy way to do it.