# Project texture onto an object in Three.js

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js

Is it possible to 'project' a texture onto an object in Three.js the way a film projector would do in real life? The intended effect is that the texture looks distorted (based on the object's shape) except for the case when the camera position === projector position.

Comment: example here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15732035/1980846

Comment: I can't see the desired effect in the example (rotating dark box only) and it throws some JS warnings / errors...

Comment: sorry forgot to mention that in order for me to make it work I had to revert back to three.js r71. (`<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/r71/three.js"></script>`)